# Cannot execute the build command in Geany

Tags: c++, ide, geany

I am having trouble executing my simple code in C++ in Geany. 
I used to work on it just fine, until all of a sudden I started to encounter an error.

Here's a screenshot of my problem:

[image]

in Edit>Preference>Tools>Terminal

I've tried the following paths in the Terminal :

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "/bin/sh"
```

I also used it without quotation

```
x-terminal-emulator -e /bin/sh
```

but that didn't work at all. What could the problem be, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please don't hide your code in an image. Include it in the post itself.

Comment: the website didn't let me do this...
So think before you judge me, man.

Comment: Sure it does. Copy paste your code, and format it properly. Either with the code sample brackets icon "{}" or by selecting the code and pressing ctrl+k. Give it a try. If it somehow shows an error, let me know what it says.

Comment: It appears to run Geany under Windows. Did you recently change your Terminal settings in Geany?

Comment: frlan yes I'm running it under Windows...
and yes I changed my terminal settings... ( but forget what i did )

Comment: Since you're using Windoze, a look at your screenshot and post tells me that your issue is with the settings. In the settings, you've given `x-terminal-emulator` which is understood by linux, however, there is no such program in windows. So you'll have to replace that `x-terminal-emulator` with `cmd.exe` with the correct switches (which I do not know).